# Carousel in the page is being stretched in landscape mode MAUI Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, maui

Carousel at the top becomes stretched and combines 2 and more images together.It works fine in IOS platform but Android does not.

This is my code in XAML:

```
<StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Border StrokeThickness="0" BackgroundColor="Beige"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20">
                    <Grid RowDefinitions="90,*,Auto"
                        ColumnDefinitions="90,*,90"
                        HeightRequest="150">
                        <CarouselView Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IndicatorView="indicatorView" ItemsSource ="{Binding carouselItems}">
                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:CarouselItem">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Images,Mode=TwoWay}" Aspect="Fill">
                                    </Image>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                            <CarouselView.GestureRecognizers>

                            </CarouselView.GestureRecognizers>
                        </CarouselView>
                        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView"
                                    IndicatorColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource PrimaryColorLight},
                                        Dark={StaticResource PrimaryColorDark}}"
                                    SelectedIndicatorColor="LightGray"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    VerticalOptions="End"
                                    Margin="10"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </StackLayout>
```

This is my code in VM:

```
private ObservableCollection<CarouselItem> _carouselItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<CarouselItem>();

        public ObservableCollection<CarouselItem> carouselItems
        {
            get { return _carouselItems; }
            set { _carouselItems = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
public someViewModel(){
carouselItems.Clear();
            carouselItems.Add(new CarouselItem
            {
                Id = "1",
                Images = "article_banner.png"
            });
            carouselItems.Add(new CarouselItem
            {
                Id = "2",
                Images = "banner_4.png"
            });
            carouselItems.Add(new CarouselItem
            {
                Id = "3",
                Images = "banner_5.png"
            });
}
```

This is the effect on the Android platform when in Vertical position:
[Vertical View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTR71.jpg)

This is the effect when I am in landscape mode:
[Landscape Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZE5x.png)

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code you provided and it is an issue on the CarouselView. I can not find any issue threads on the GitHub. So you can report it as a new issue.

Here is the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) to post the new issue.